# Blocking the producer in multiprocessing Python queues

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using a multiprocessing queue with one producer and 2 consumers.
Below is a minimal example

```
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue
import time
import os
import numpy as np
q = JoinableQueue(maxsize=2)

def producer():
    for i in range (500):
        # put 2 random numbers into the queue
        r1 = np.random.randint(1, 100)
        q.put(r1)
        r2 = np.random.randint(1, 100)
        q.put(r2)
        print('New Producer', r1, r2, time.ctime())
        i = i + 1
        time.sleep(5)


def worker1():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        pid = os.getpid()
        print(f'pid {pid} Working on {item}')
        print(f'pid {pid} Finished {item}')

def worker2():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        pid = os.getpid()
        print(f'pid {pid} Working on {item}')
        print(f'pid {pid} Finished {item}')


Process(target=worker1, daemon=True).start()
Process(target=worker2, daemon=True).start()


p = Process(target=producer)
p.start()
p.join()

q.join()
```

Which gives

```
New Producer 16 10 Wed Mar 20 12:03:08 2024
pid 25621 Working on 16
pid 25621 Finished 16
pid 25622 Working on 10
pid 25622 Finished 10
New Producer 97 34 Wed Mar 20 12:03:13 2024
pid 25621 Working on 97
pid 25621 Finished 97
pid 25622 Working on 34
pid 25622 Finished 34
...
```

If I just modify `worker1` like:

```
def worker1():
    while True:
        time.sleep(500)
```

Then the second worker retrieves both numbers:

```
New Producer 9 7 Wed Mar 20 12:05:18 2024
pid 25812 Working on 9
pid 25812 Finished 9
pid 25812 Working on 7
pid 25812 Finished 7
New Producer 91 27 Wed Mar 20 12:05:23 2024
pid 25812 Working on 91
pid 25812 Finished 91
pid 25812 Working on 27
pid 25812 Finished 27
```

Is There a way to prevent this and basically block the producer if there has been a problem with worker1 ?

Comment: How about using separate queues of size 1 for each process? As an aside: (1) What is the point in `producer` calling `sleep`? (2) The statement `i = i + 1` in `producer` accomplishes nothing in addition to it being non-Pythonic. (3) There is no reason to be using a `JoinableQueue` since you are not calling its `task_done` method. (4) Move `pid = os.getpid()` obefore the loop entrance. (5) But why would you event want to block the producer? Let the second consumer pick up the slack.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes. Now, why would you want that? And what exactly do you want to happen instead? The point of such a setup is typically that one blocked (or slightly longer running) job will not block overall job execution. What are your goals instead?

Comment: If the consumer is too slow, then it will not have time to proceed the data before the next iteration.

Comment: You have placed a maximum size on the queue so even if the producer was able to produce items to put on the queue faster than consumers can process them, the queue cannot grow beyond a size of 2 and the producer will automatically block until the number of items on the queue becomes less than 2. So even if one of the consumers dies, the other consumer will do all the work as you can see in your output. It's still not clear what your issue with this is.